# I have class A, which contains class B, I want to use class A in class B without instantiating class A

Tags: c#, class, scope, chromium

Hopefully the title is fairly clear, but here is a bit more detail:

Class A contains a ChromeDriver variable and methods that operate on it. I Have defined class B within class A that represents a menu, and I need access to some of the methods of class A in class B.

Another way to put the question: How do I get access to Class A (outer class) from Class B (inner class) without creating another instance of Class A?

I'm still very new to C# and so far haven't found a way to do this, my research so far has only turned up dead ends. Is it possible? And if not, why not??

Thank you for any answers and pointers in the right direction!

-- Update --

Sorry for the long delay, here is the situation in which above is required:

```
 public sealed class CatalogPane
 {

    protected CatalogPane(Application application, string automationId, int index)
    {
        Pane = application.MainWindow.FindElementByClassName("CatalogMenu")
            .Where(item => item.AutomationId().StartsWith(automationId))
            .ElementAtOrDefault(index);
    }

    public AppiumWebElement Pane { get; set; }

    public static class contextMenu
    {       

        public static void Select(MenuOption option) // MenuOption has property id that holds an automationId
        {
            Pane.FindElementByAccessibilityId(option.id).Click(); // I do not have access to Pane so this is not possible. I would like to be able to do this.
        }

    }
 }
```

Comment: "I Have defined class B within class A". What does that mean? Can you provide sample code?

Comment: The question isn't nearly clear enough. Please provide code showing the issue, so we can at least start to deciper the problem

Comment: You need to show us some code.  You should also provide us a high-level description of what your objective is.

Comment: [What's the best way of accessing field in the enclosing class from the nested class?](//stackoverflow.com/q/185124)

Comment: `Car` class contains `Passenger` class. `Car` has method `ConsumeFuel()`, why can't `Car.Passenger` also `ConsumeFuel()`? Because `Car` and `Passenger` are completely different things and stuff that is possible for one isn't necessarily possible for the other. Now an *instance* of `Car.Passenger` might be able to *use* an *instance* of `Car` and make that instance do `ConsumeFuel()`. But then it would still be the car that does the consuming, not the passenger.

Answer (score 3):

I apologize - this should really be a comment, but I do not have enough reputation points to comment...
If you need to use a method from your outer class in your inner class, it sounds like your division of labor is wrong (your objects should be doing what they need done). But without seeing any code, we can't know what your actual goal is. 
Maybe it should be a method of class B, and if you need it in class A then use an instance of B?

Answer (score 1):

The good approach would be to make it possible that you can give class B a reference to your class A for example give class B a second (or do it in the first) constructor where you pass the instance of A. Maybe when class A is instantied:

```cs
Class A {
    Class A() {
        this.b = new B(this);
    }
/// Rest of A
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to what I understood this would be the example you need.

```
public class A 
{
    public B ClassB { get; private set; }

    public A()
    {
        ClassB = new B(this); //pass the parent class as a parameter
    }

    public class B
    {
        private A ClassA { get; set; } //With this property you can access the values of class A

        public B(A _classA)
        {
            ClassA = _classA;
        }
    }
}
```